# Error while trying to install scikit-fda in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a Python 3.7.10 environnement on jupyter notebook and i want to install scikit-fda library. but it gives me an error **Building wheel for fdasrsf**

I tried

```
pip install scikit-fda
```

and i get this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fdasrsf
Building wheel for fdasrsf (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for fdasrsf (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[24 lines of output\]
src/dp_grid.c: In function ‘dp_costs’:
src/dp_grid.c:31:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions \[-Wsign-compare\]
for ( i=0; i\<dp_nbhd_count; ++i )
^
src/dp_nbhd.c: In function ‘compute_nbhd_count_rec’:
src/dp_nbhd.c:68:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for(size_t j = 2; j \<= n; j++) {
^
src/dp_nbhd.c:68:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
src/dp_nbhd.c: In function ‘compute_nbhd_count’:
src/dp_nbhd.c:104:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for(size_t i = 0; i \< n + 1; states\[i++\] = -1);
^
src/dp_nbhd.c: In function ‘dp_generate_nbhd’:
src/dp_nbhd.c:136:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for(size_t i = 1; i \<= nbhd_dim; i++) {
^
src/dp_nbhd.c:137:9: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
for(size_t j = 1; j \<= nbhd_dim; j++) {
^
not modified: 'build/\_DP.c'
generating build/\_DP.c
(already up-to-date)
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fdasrsf
Failed to build fdasrsf
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fdasrsf, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Does someone have the same problem, please if you know how to successuful solve this problem, do not hesitate to give me ur suggestions.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519130/jupyter-notebook-how-to-execute-system-shell-commands-in-the-right-conda-enviro

Comment: @alec_djinn unfortunately no, I still have the same error after executing :

import sys

!$sys.executable -m pip install scikit-fda